# Getting the world space camera direction in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a camera node in my SceneKit scene that is setup to allow the user to orbit by offsetting it's pivot:

```
self.cameraNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -100);
```

The user then rotates the node to orbit the camera.

What I would like to work out is

A) how to get the world space direction the camera is facing at any given time

and then

B) how to convert that direction to x,y,z components I can use to move the camera node relative to the way the camera is facing (forward/back/left/right from the camera's perspective).

Thanks!